# Single CPU 100% by lspci

Tags: fedora, cpu, pci

On Fedora, the lspci command keeps staying at ~100% while I'm not doing anything with my computer. I've done a clean install last week and before that I also had this problem.

Top output gives me:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
10283 tim       20   0   19384   1436   1312 R 100.0  0.0  14:34.63 lspci       
 1752 tim       20   0  624948 144552 109544 S   8.0  1.8   3:49.61 Xorg        
11197 tim       20   0  612712  48612  36336 S   2.0  0.6   0:18.19 gnome-syst+ 
·
·
```

and if I check system monitor, i see that only 1 cpu running at ~100%.

[image: CPU Usage]

Besides, if I try to run the command 'lspci' it just keeps loading and not showing anything.

Some info about my system:

```
Fedora 27 (up-to-date)
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
Core(s) per socket:  4
RAM memory: 8G
```

Comment: Is this a laptop?

Comment: Do a system update, this is a known lspci bug that is already fixed. (...)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes it is a laptop. I've done a dnf --refresh upgrade, and I was up to date already.

Answer (score 2):

You have to figure which process invokes `lspci`. Replace `lspci` binary with script. Rename it to `lspci.bin` (issue commands below as `root` user):

```
mv /usr/bin/lspci /usr/bin/lspci.bin
```

Create script:

```
touch /usr/bin/lspci
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/lspci
```

Open created script with your favorite text editor (let it be `nano` for instance)

```
nano /usr/bin/lspci
```

and copy/paste the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo lspci "$@" >> /var/log/lspci.log
date >> /var/log/lspci.log
pstree >> /var/log/lspci.log
exec lspci.bin "$@"
```

Reboot computer, check if the `lspci` CPU overload problem exists, open the log file `/var/log/lspci.log` and try to explain whats happened. If you can't find a reason of the problem, post the content of the log and ask for additional support.

If the problem has gone away, revert back everything:

```
rm -f /usr/bin/lspci
mv /usr/bin/lspci.bin /usr/bin/lspci
rm -f /var/log/lspci.log
reboot
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried you method and it did disappear. Also the command lspci works again.

Comment: @Jasper Could you post your lspci.log?